# Android Custom Content Provider

Tags: android, provider

I'm developing Custom content provider in my app. And face issuel when get list from custom content provider. Detail, my custom content provider contain a Table. I just want get all object in this table. But it not working. This is my code, please show me what thing i wrong ?

```
 public void onAdd(View v) {
    String name = edtname.getText().toString();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://homework.iuh.hh.customcontentprovider.AccountProvider/accounts");
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("NAME", name);
    getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
}

public void getList(View v) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://homework.iuh.hh.customcontentprovider.AccountProvider/accounts");

    Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String res=  "";
    while(!c.isAfterLast())
    {
        res += c.getString(0);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    c.close();
    Log.i(TAG,res);

And it is query method in content provider

public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Log.i(TAG,"query()");
    Cursor c = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri,projection,selection,selectionArgs,sortOrder);
    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(),uri);
    return c;
}
```

In method onAdd(), it working fine. But with method getList, it show log, query function is called very time. and crash app with message 
 `E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
05-21 11:07:43.661 5876-5876/? E/AndroidRuntime: Error reporting crash
                                                 android.os.TransactionTooLargeException`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to be as follows:
`Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(uri,null,null,null,null);
 String res=  "";
 while(c.moveToNext()){
   res += c.getString(0);
 }
 c.close();
 Log.i(TAG,res);`

The real problem is that your Content Provider is just endlessly looping in your query method. You need to actually execute the SQL here, not call the content resolver. Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) class